# Android AccountManager's getAuthToken returns null

Tags: android, oauth, accountmanager, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm currently trying to implement `AccountManager` to my project. Creating the account works well, I can access the *AuthToken* without problem.

However, once I refresh and update the *AuthToken*  in the `AccountManager`, I can't seem to access it anymore as `AccountManager.getAuthToken()` returns `null` every time and I end up refreshing the token every single time I try to access it.

Here's my `getAuthToken()` method:

```
public static String getAuthToken(final Context context)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "getAuthToken");
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    String accountType = context.getResources().getString(R.string.account_type);
    Account accounts[] = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType);

    if (accounts.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    /* This method retrieves the token for the given account but doesn't pop the Authentication Page if not found */
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> futureBundle = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_TYPE, null, false, null, null);
    Bundle bundle;
    try {
        bundle = futureBundle.getResult();
    } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "operation canceled: " + ex.getMessage());

        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage());

        return null;
    } catch (AuthenticatorException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "AccountManagerUtility getAuthToken: " + bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
    return bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
}
```

And here's the method updating the AccountManager:

```
public static void updateAccount(Context context, final OAuthToken authToken)
{
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    String accountType = context.getResources().getString(R.string.account_type);
    Account accounts[] = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType);
    if (accounts.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    accountManager.setAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_TYPE, authToken.getAccessToken());
    accountManager.setPassword(accounts[0], authToken.getRefreshToken());

    final long timestamp = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
    setRefreshTokenTimestamp(context, timestamp); // Updates User data
}
```

Permissions are set in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

And Authenticator is also defined. Actually, after `updateAccount` has been called, the Authenticator's `getAuthToken` is being called and that's the method that refreshes the token.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get AuthToken from your App's account instead:

```
AccountManager accountManager=AccountManager.get(getContext());
    String     oAuth=accountManager.peekAuthToken(account,"oauth");
```

> `accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_TYPE, null, false, null, null);`

is now deprecated.